# Ensure my function returns mutated object as instanceof the same class typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects, immutability

```
export const FilterUndefined = <T extends object>(obj: T): T => {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    return value ? { ...acc, [key]: value } : acc;
  }, {}) as T;
};
```

I'm migrating a database and part of cleaning up the old data structure, some of the values for some keys end up being literaly `undefined`. The key will still exist and will have the value `undefined`

I made this function but after modifying a class object with it, it will no longer be an instanceof the same class. How could I make this return an object that's instanceof the same class as the input parameter?

The as T makes TS compiler shut up but that's it.

I've also tried to get the prototype of that object and `return new prototype(obj)` or `return new prototype.constructor(obj)`

The console log of the prototype looks like this:

```
PROTOTYPE TestClass {}
```

I'm testing using this setup:

```
  it('should return the same type that it receives', () => {
    class TestClass {
      name: string;
      optionalProperty?: any;
    }

    let testObject = new TestClass();
    testObject.name = 'My Name';
    testObject.optionalProperty = undefined;

    console.log(testObject instanceof TestClass);
    testObject = FilterUndefined(testObject);

    console.log(testObject instanceof TestClass);
    console.log(testObject);

    expect(testObject).instanceOf(TestClass);
  });
```

EDIT: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3sdg98xt/2/ but copy-pasted from vscode without any issues running it i'm getting an error 'execpted expression, got ';'

Comment: Does setting the `initialValue` parameter to `new T` or `new obj.constructor` work? This might have some side effects though.

Comment: Are you OK with mutating the input object?

Comment: @carlosvin for the usage of this function I'd preffer it, seems to me that returning a new instance would add complexity/use resources when it is not necessary. 

There is no context at all where I'd need the object to have `key: undefined`

Comment: @adiga what do you mean? The class I'm trying to get stuff of is 'TestClass' -- I'm creating the object as new TestClass(),

Comment: @MichaelB Then I might have a simple solution, check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will mutate the input object by removing the keys with undefined values.

```js
function removeUndefined <T>(object: T): T {
    for (const id in object) {
       if (object[id] === undefined) {
          delete object[id];
       }
    }
    return object;
}
```

It seems it works for your test case: [Test in typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=25&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8CwAoaB0AdmALbwBc0yATgJZEDmA3HodAPYAOSdHJIAAo1u8GkgCeAfipgiE1rgC+ePADMArkWC9+0GvFIcAbvACqRACbw1DeJYA8sAHwAKDgCMAVvB1VYAJT+WGyEahw00K7A-MjQdJbxRJzevkgBIfjsBHRqUZ4+OgDaCQC60AC8VdBa1rZE9hk4WdmE1iDwSPAphUgllqWKrdAqLSOhBAZIGjTJBWmKo6q4HUjQXcgA8qk6lcTwAO5wiKjoEK4BihtI270AdCTkewDkALIS0AByZPDPVye3NJ3bi6ATCUTiD4VGpWGx2SyKPAxIgQDgdO4gDiMVzXQE6S54XE7NbQgxGUwWOrwnEA4kE3DI1HozHYom9elI2Jo+AYrE0rbEpLIOTAeAcPIIZBoSAQenQIA)

Comment: I really ddin't want to change the fundamental way the function works but nothing really seemed to work, ended up just using it as this. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with each iteration of `reduce` you are returning a new `{}` which is an instance `Object`.

So to make the return object of same instace as of argument you should make following changes.

```
export const FilterUndefined = (obj) => {
return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    if (value) {acc[key] = value;}
    else {delete acc[key]}
    return  acc;
  }, new obj.constructor);
};
```

or you can use `new obj.__proto__.constructor` as per the `target` of typescript output you are using.

Reply in case you have typescript issues with this code snippet.

Comment: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'. ` and then `The initial value of Object.prototype.constructor is the standard built-in Object constructor.` for the last call

Comment: Use `obj.__proto__.constructor` not `Object.prototype.constructor`. Also I have made some changes. try now

Comment: `Property '__proto__' does not exist on type 'T'` could also use (obj as any).__proto ... to make it shut up, but then it doesn't work, the resulting obj is not an instance of a class